# What is the general solution to the first order differential equation $dy/dx =(x^3 - 2y)/x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm kind of stuck on this. Some working out and feedback would be appreciated.

The differential equation is

$$y'=\frac{x^3-2y}{x}$$

Comment: if you have a book or notes, read about "integration factor" Then you can see why Lab made that move about multiplying both sides by factor $x$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

So, we have $$x\ dy+2y\ dx=x^3\ dx$$

Multiplying either sides by $x\ne0,$

$$ x^2\ dy+y\cdot 2x\ dx=x^4\ dx\implies d(x^2 y)=x^4\ dx$$

Reference : Integrating factor [1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)