# What is the general solution to the first order DE $\;dy/dx =-y +xy^2\;$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Kinda stuck on how to solve this one.

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -y + xy^2$$

Comment: Did you just look at it and give up? Did you search for ODEs looking like yours? A hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

Comment: Thought about separating?

Comment: @math12 You can't separate immediately...

Comment: no i eliminated some methods i can't use separating the variables and I tried finding a way of solving it by making it into an exact equation but i couldn't find a way to solve it then i used the integrating factor method and i still couldn't find a way. That's why i posted here.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653406/what-is-the-general-solution-to-the-first-order-differential-equation-dy-dx-x

Comment: i think i worked it out thanks to the hint on bernoulli equations but im not sure if my solution is correct can anyone check my answers please. I used the substitution u = 1/y and i end up with an answer 1/(-xe^x + e^x -c) is this right

Answer (score 3):

In light of @Siminore's comment, let's solve this Bernoulli ODE. Rewriting the equation gives us $$y'+y=xy^{\color{red}{2}}$$ Bu setting $u=y^{1-\color{red}{2}}=y^{\color{blue}{-1}}$ we get this new one $$u'+\color{blue}{-1}u=\color{blue}{-1}x\to u'-u=-x$$ so $$d(e^{-x}u)=-xe^{-x}\to e^{-x}u=(1+x)e^{-x}+C\to u(x)=(1+x)+Ce^{x}$$

Comment: nice answer @b.s.

Comment: I like this answer. Excellent!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: What is your wife's status? Is she OK?

Comment: @B.S. Alhamdulillah she is now better. Thank you brother.